# Binding issue with Flex and TextBox in sapui5

Tags: jquery, sapui5

I am having a strange issue with respect to binding for text field on SAPUI5 . The formatter function does not receive the data

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setData({Components : "5",
                        TotalComponents : "7"});

        var oText = new sap.m.Text({
            text : {
                path : "Components",
                formatter : function(d){

                    return "Solved Messages in "+d+" Components";

                }
            },
            visible : true
        });
        oText.setModel(oModel);
        oText.placeAt("content");
```

I can see that in debugger the binding path for text field is correct.

```
this.getModel(this.getBindingContext().sPath)
```

also returns the correct value but the formatter function receives only null.

Can you tell me if i am missing some syntax?
Code sample - [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/fuxufujoku/edit?html,output)

Thanks and Regards,
Veera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

instead of "Components" use "/Components"